# TopCoder Coding environment linker error

Tags: c++

I am trying to submit a solution to a problem in TopCoder, ***which requires a submission to follow its predefined classes and methods***. Since I am new to TopCoder, I am mostly trying to adjust to the coding interface. This code compiles perfectly on my computer. Unfortunately on TopCoder, I have been getting the errors: 
Your code did not compile:

errors linking:

AdditionGame-stub.o: In function `main':
AdditionGame-stub.cc:(.text.startup+0x0): multiple definition of`main'
AdditionGame.o:AdditionGame-stub.cc:(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Help Please. Here is my code:

```
 class AdditionGame {

public:

int getMaximumPoints(int a, int b, int c, int n){
        int temp;
        if(a<b){temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}
        if(b<c){temp=b; b=c; c=temp;}

        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(a>0){sum=sum+a;}
            if(a>0){a=a-1;}
            if(a<b){temp=a; a=b; b=temp;}
        if(b<c){temp=b; b=c; c=temp;}
        }

        return sum;
    }

};


#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    AdditionGame add;
int A,B,C,N;

cin>>A>>B>>C>>N;

int p = add.getMaximumPoints(A, B, C, N);
 cout<<p;
return 0;
}`
```

Comment: perhaps it has its own main, that is supposed to call your function

Comment: Thanks a lot! Removing the code after int main() solved the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like TopCoder is defining the main() function for you, based on your error message.